# Исключение Firebird "invalid BLOB handle"

Tags: c#, firebird, typed-dataset

При обычном Fill'e DataTable выкидывает исключение. Причем, когда запускаешь приложение не из студии, все проходит успешно.

```
   в FirebirdSql.Data.Client.Managed.Version10.GdsDatabase.ProcessResponse(IResponse response)
   в FirebirdSql.Data.Client.Managed.Version10.GdsDatabase.ReadResponse()
   в FirebirdSql.Data.Client.Managed.Version10.GdsDatabase.ReadGenericResponse()
   в FirebirdSql.Data.Client.Managed.Version10.GdsBlob.GetSegment()
   в FirebirdSql.Data.Common.BlobBase.Read()
   в FirebirdSql.Data.Common.DbValue.GetBlobData(Int64 blobId)
   в FirebirdSql.Data.Common.DbValue.GetBinary()
   в FirebirdSql.Data.Common.DbValue.GetValue()
   в FirebirdSql.Data.Common.DbValue.get_Value()
   в FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbDataReader.<>c__DisplayClass1.<GetValue>b__0()
   в FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbDataReader.CheckedGetValue[T](Func`1 f)
```

Есть вариант нажать F5 и выполнение продолжится дальше. Однако, это раздражает.

Comment: Debug -> Exceptions -> снять галку с CLR Exceptions или найти/добавить только это

Answer (score 1):

Названия таблицы типы данных/границы /возможные значения проверить все  особенно null, попробовать использовать другие типы  просто упростить запрос к минимуму для эксперимента и постепенно усложнять пока не проявиться ошибка.

Comment: Бывает, что ошибка не каждый раз появляется.

Comment: Работает через раз именно со студии?(и с какой частотой) Какая версия студии? Предоставьте минимальный неработающий проект? То что я описал все перепробовали?

Answer (score 0):

В главном меню Visual Studio: Debug->Exceptions и снимай все галки, которые видишь.

Comment: Это не решение проблемы, как я понимаю, а просто ее игнорирование

Comment: @IsM, а ты уверен, что это не какое-нибудь левое "first chance exception", раз программа правильно работает и без дебага запускается нормально?

Comment: Ну именно этого косяка не проскакивает

Answer (score 0):

В Delphi были аналогичные проблемы при использовании BDE, может Вам чем то поможет.

> -- BDE ADMINISTRATOR HELP --
>
> BLOBS TO CACHE
>
> Determines how many BLOBs will be cached on the client. Applications that deal with fetching dead BLOBs using dead table opens or queries can set a limit on the number of BLOBs to cache depending on the resource available on the client.
>
> Setting a value 100 means the application can work with a maximum of 100 BLOB records cached. Fetching more than 100, then scrolling back 100 records results in an "Invalid Blob handle in record buffer" error message.
>
> This parameter does not apply to live table opens.
>
> Default Value: 64
> Range : >64 and < 65536

При этом побороть это можно так: запустить BDEAdmin, открыть базу данных, с которой происходит работа и изменяем в настройках свойство "BLOBS TO CACHE = 65000". Это свойство показывает, сколько записей кэшировать при SQL-запросах. Оно не может превышать 64К. Но все же никогда нет гарантии, что и этот CACHE не будет переполнен.

Больше информации можно почитать [тут](http://fido7.ru.delphi.db.narkive.com/mIGpybyG/d6-bde-blob-invalid-blob-handle-0x272e)